# Any way to use goog.require in development with convention-over-configuration?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library, convention-over-configur

Is there any way I can use Google Closure `goog.require` to manage JS dependencies, without having to register each namespace explicitly in a dependencies.js file?

I like the idea of the compiler for production, but for development, I'd like some kind of convention-over-configuration translation of namespace to JS folder/path such that something like `goog.require('myapp.module')` automatically imports `myapp/module.js` in development mode (if not already imported), while in production it all gets compiled into a single file.

I seem to remember old versions of `dojo.require` worked this way. Any idea if Google Closure can do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can use Google Closure `goog.require` to manage JS dependencies, without having to register each namespace explicitly in a dependencies.js file?

The short answer is no. In *uncompiled* JavaScript code, `goog.require()` relies on a dependency graph generated by calls to `goog.addDependency(relativePath, provides, requires).`

From the [DepsWriter](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/depswriter) documentation:

> But how does Closure Library know which files provide which namespaces? Included in Closure Library is a default *dependency file* named **[deps.js](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/deps.js)**. This file contains one line for every JavaScript file in the library, each specifying the file location (relative to **[base.js](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/base.js)**), the namespaces it provides, and the namespace it requires.
>
> In debug mode, a `goog.require()` statement looks to see if the require namespace was specified and, if so, fetch the files that provide it and all of its dependencies.
>
> However, Closure Library only comes with a dependency file for the namespaces in the library. **If you plan to write your own namespaces (and you likely will), you can use `depswriter.py` to make a dependency file for the namespaces you create.**

That being said, you could use a tool such as [plovr](http://plovr.com/), which provides a "RAW" mode to concatenate your JavaScript sources without compilation. This avoids the need to generate a deps file, but it also means that when debugging code in the browser, it is more challenging to determine the original file containing the code.

Comment: it sounds like this is the correct answer although not the one I was hoping to hear.

Answer (score 2):

In the Closure tools there is a python script called calcdeps.py which generates exactly what you want.

Getting started with goog.provide/goog.require:

- Organize your files into a directory structure to match the namespace(s) you desire. i.e. If you're declaring the namespace 'grantys.awesome.lib.Math', your directory structure should look something like grantys/awesome/lib/Math.js.
- In each file you're adding as a dependency, the first javascript function call should be goog.provide('grantys.awesome.lib.Math'). To depend on another file or files, declare the requirement with goog.require('grantys.awesome.lib.Constants'). *this is important, goog.provide is what calcdeps.py uses to figure out what each file can provide -- **uncompiled it makes absolutely zero guarantee that the namespace you say you're providing is what you're constructing in that file.**
- Run calcdeps.py with the proper arguments (paths to search for files which may or may not contain goog.provide('some.library'), the filename to write, etc). This will generate a file containing any goog.addDependency statements you'd otherwise have written manually. Also note, the deps file calcdeps generates uses relative paths, as seen from the directory in which you're writing the output file (not always the directory from which you run the command)

An example of the output of calcdeps.py:

```
goog.addDependency("../site/ui/MurphyBed.js", ['site.ui.MurphyBed', 'site.ui.MurphyBed.State', 'site.ui.MurphyBed.EventType', 'site.ui.MurphyBed.Error'], ['goog.dom', 'goog.object', 'goog.events', 'goog.events.EventTarget', 'site.fx.easing', 'goog.fx.dom', 'goog.fx.AnimationSerialQueue']);
goog.addDependency("../site/ui/SliderButton.js", ['site.ui.SliderButton'], ['goog.ui.CustomButton', 'site.ui.SliderButtonRenderer', 'goog.fx.dom', 'site.fx.easing']);
```

- In your html, include google's base.js script. This declares the goog object.
  After the base.js script tag, add a tag which references your generated deps.js file you made using calcdeps.py above.
- Load your dependencies using goog.require('grantys.awesome.lib.Math').

**Note: If you change a dependency, you must rerun calcdeps.py.** My own solution was to wrap it in a shell script with the correct args, so when I make a change that requires the files to be rescaned, I just run ./calcdeps.sh

Comment: I'm aware of calcdeps.py.  I was hoping to avoid it during development, mostly because it's an extra moving part between making changes and seeing them take effect with Eclipse/WTP.

Comment: It's not as much of an extra hassle as you might think. You only need to run calcdeps when you change a provide or require statement in one of your sources, it doesn't actually parse the class itself for information on methods or properties, that happens in Eclipse's source scanning.

Comment: if you're used to making any changes to HTML/JS and just hitting "republish" in Eclipse, then yeah, it's an extra step.

Answer (score 1):

The `base.js` file defines the function `goog.require()`. The function call `goog.require('goog.dom')` loads the JavaScript file that defines the functions in the `goog.dom` namespace, along with any other files from the Closure Library that those functions need.

Comment: doesn't answer the question.  Asking about how I can use goog.require for MY application's modules, not about loading the other goog.* modules.